# Visual Studio LNK2001 Error, despite using extern "C" for ffmpeg libraries in C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, ffmpeg

This is what it  looks like:

'''

```
extern "C"
{
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/avutil.h"
};
```

'''

But I still get these errors when using the **FFmpeg** libraries in **Visual Studio 2019**

```
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol avformat_open_input
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_read_frame
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_free
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_get_sample_fmt_name
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol avformat_close_input
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_init_packet
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol avcodec_receive_frame
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol avcodec_open2
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_sample_fmt_is_planar
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol avcodec_close
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_get_bytes_per_sample
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_packet_unref
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol avformat_find_stream_info
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_find_best_stream
1>AudioFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol av_frame_alloc
```

I would be greatfull to anyone who could help me resolve this. I am using C++ for Windows.

Comment: Why did you wrapped `#include`s with `extern "C"`? Did you add the libraries in linker settings?

Comment: The FFMPEG files are C files, so the need to be wrapped before they could be used in C++. But this results in errors too.

Comment: `extern "C"` is not used to indicate that the library is written in C. It is used to prevent name mangling. Could you please capture your VS project settings and upload the image?